# Read password protected excel file without out using OLEDB in c#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

How to read password protect excel file without out using OLEDB in C# WPF application. I'm using OLEDB to read now as given below, but now I wanted this to be changed as requirement changed.

```
objWB.Unprotect(Password);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is **NOT** a code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using EPPLUS, I really don't know what your problem is:

```
var path = @"path/file.xlsx";
var file = new FileInfo(path);
var package = new ExcelPackage(file, "password");
```